# PSPDFKIT, cordova integration

Tags: pspdfkit

I am trying to integrate PSPDFKIT in cordova.

```
PSPDFKit.showDocumentFromAssets('Layout.pdf', {
        title: 'My PDF Document',
        page: 4,
        scrollDirection: PSPDFKit.PageScrollDirection.VERTICAL,
        scrollMode: PSPDFKit.ScrollMode.CONTINUOUS,
        useImmersiveMode: true
    },success(success){
        console.log('success')
    },fail(fail){
        console.log(fail);
    });
```

This code give error at success.

Comment: If you get an error, please include it (as text) so other searching for the same error can find your question

Comment: Please contact PSPDFKit support at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/